# SwiftUI - Disabling Button Highlight on Swipe

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, tabview

I'm dealing with a simple button in SwiftUI layed out as follows:

```
TabView {
  ForEach(...) { ...
    Button {...}
      label {...}
  }
}
```

When I tap (but do not release) the button, it highlights the button by default; this is fine. However, if I have these buttons arranged in a paged tab view, then swiping to navigate through the pages highlights the buttons, which I do not want.

Is there anyway to disable this highlighting? Preferably, I'd like to keep the highlight when tapping the button but not when swiping, but if I have to disable it altogether that's fine as well.

Comment: Hey! Did you find solutions or workarounds? Thanks

Comment: Let me get back to you in a few days.